# Can't find object on loaded scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a save system and everything is working perfectly except one thing. When game is loading scene with actual level saved position of player won't set. I've tried to load it in additive mode and then unload the previous scene, but console only shows me  that player couldn't be found. I checked multiple times for typo.

It worked one time when i putted function for checking if game was loaded. It looked like this

```
is_loaded = true;
SceneManager.LoadScene("scene_to_load");
```

And in another script linked with object on level

```
void Start()
{
    if (is_loaded)
    {
        load();
    }
}

void load()
{
//actual loading code
}
```

It's working but i don't like how this work. There must be a better way to do that.

Comment: Are you talking about when you are loading sceneA on application start or being in sceneA with player and then loading sceneB?

Comment: No, let's say scene A is a menu and scene B is "game" with player.

Comment: Have you tried putting the load code in a LateUpdate() ?

Comment: Still nothing. I've made now a load() function called by button in menu. At te end of code i have code for loading scene and setting player postion. Maybe there is a metod for chcecking if scene is already loaded, because it might be a reason why it coudn't find player.

Comment: I used OnLevelWasLoaded(int) and bool already used for checking for starting new game and it's working.